# mysql bind-address vs mysqlx-bind-address setting to allow remote connection

Tags: mysql

I've found a new setting variable in the mysql 8.0 config file (mysqlx-bind-address)

Should i set it to: 0.0.0.0 with the bind address to allow remote connection?

Example:

```
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
mysqlx-bind-address     = 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

setting `bind-adress` is sufficient `mysqlx-bind-address` is for the `X plugin`
if you want to know more about the `X plugin` you can go [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/01/07/understanding-mysql-x-all-flavors/)